# Make a JLabel text vertically aligned to the center

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel, layout-manager

How do I make a `JLabel` text vertically and horizontally aligned to the center?

I have to make use of `setHorizontalTextPosition` and `setVerticalTextPosition`. Can this be achieved by using these 2?

I have tried but the text remains at the top itself.

```
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class label extends JFrame
{
  private JLabel label;

    public label() //constructor
    {
      super("Simple GUI");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      label=new JLabel("Centered JLabel");
      label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      add(label);
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). That code only needs a `main` method to make it an MRE / SSCCE. 2) Put the label as the only component with no constraint, into a `GridBagLayout` - it will be centered both horizontally & vertically.

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: .. 4) Always read the documentation for the methods being called. `setHorizontalTextPosition` does not do what you seem to think it does. The method needed here includes the term `Alignment`. 5) Add a visible border (e.g. a `LineBorder`) to components when debugging a layout or alignment problem. It can reveal some surprising results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried but the text remains at the top itself.

You have two problems:

1. Andrew addressed the first problem. You are using the wrong method.
2. Next you are using the wrong layout. The FlowLayout only display components on a single line so the component will always be at the top. Don't change the layout manager. The default layout manager for a JFrame is the `BorderLayout`. When you add a component to the `CENTER` (which is the default when you don't specify a constraint), the component will be sized to fill the entire frame. Then the "alignment" properties will control the position of the text within the size allocated to the label.

Or a different option is to use a `GridBagLayout`. Then you don't need to play with alignment options of the component:

```
setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
add(label, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Try both options as both may be effective in different situations.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to better understand how each layout manager works.

Answer (score -2):

I'm very sorry to don't know why the setHorizontalTextPosition method and the setVerticalTextPosition method doesn't work.

But, I'll let you know that there're several ways to sort the text in the label by inserting parameters an alignment with String when we create the label.

**First of all, camickr's answer is the best answer, Because Swing was designed to be used with layout managers!!**

**Please remember that the most recommended method is to apply GridBagLayout() to the Layout of JFrame by camickr.**

> This answer is intended to inform you that 
>   **This method is also possible, but not recommended in the normal case**
>
> Using this method is not recommended because changing the size of the frame
>   keeps the components in place, but it could give you a little help
>   when it is indicated that the size and location of components in the
>   container are used in a way that can be used in special cases, such as
>   when they need to be fixed without external impact.

To get a better idea of the problem, I'll simply change the code that you uploaded to me so that it can be executed.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

 import java.awt.Color;

public class StackOver extends JFrame
{
  private JLabel label;

    public StackOver() //constructor
    {
      super("Simple GUI");
      setLayout(null);
      setSize(500,300);     

      label=new JLabel("Centered JLabel", JLabel.CENTER); 


      /*
      label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);*/

      add(label);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new StackOver();
    }
 }
```

[image]

Hmm, let's put some color in JLabel's background to find out more.

```
label.setOpaque(true);            //Transparency Settings
label.setBackground(Color.pink);      //Specify background color
//to use 'Color' class, We must import java.awt.Color;
```

[image]

the JFrame setting was set to `FlowLayout()`which makes the location and size of components were fixed, so we couldn't see it working!

So now we're going to go through the next two processes.
1) Changing JFrame's layout to null to use Absolute Layout ("not recommended, just a case")
2) Changing the size and location of the JLabel
after the progress we can see that the text alignment works!

**1) Changing JFrame's Layout**

the [following link: Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) shows that there are so many Layouts outside of FlowLayout.

**Swing is designed to use the layout manager**, so of course you should use one of the Layout above link.

But, to use an interesting way that fix the location and size of components absolutely We will switch to `setLayout(null);`!

**2) Changing the size and location of the JLabel**

We can directly change the size and position of JLabel with [`setBounds(int startX, int startY, int Width, int Height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds-int-int-int-int-) method!

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

 import java.awt.Color;

public class StackOver extends JFrame
{
  private JLabel label;

    public StackOver() //constructor
    {
      super("Simple GUI");
      setLayout(null);
      setSize(500,300);


      label=new JLabel("Centered JLabel", JLabel.CENTER); 
      // Since it also sets the size of the JLabel, 
      //let's use the constructor to set the alignment of the text inside the JLabel.

      label.setOpaque(true);                //Transparency Settings
      label.setBackground(Color.pink);      //Specify background color
      //to use 'Color' class, We must import java.awt.Color;

      Rectangle r = this.getBounds();       //to get Frame Size
      label.setBounds(r.x+100, r.y+100, r.width-200, r.height-200);

      /*
      label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);*/

      add(label);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new StackOver();
    }
 }
```

[image]

Now we can see the text of JLabel in the middle as intended!

This method can directly fix the size and location of all components (ex buttons), but the location and size of the components are fixed even if the window size of the JFrame changes after the program runs.

so If you really want set components Absolutely by this way, you rather to set JFrame Resizable false by adding below code on JFrame's code

```
this.setResizable(false);
```

I hope the answer was helpful to you and  have a peaceful day!

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The code you posted does NOT CENTER the text. 1) The logic does not consider the borders of the frame and 2) the component will not be repositioned if the size of the frame is changed.

Comment: @camickr aha, Thank you for teaching me! For your effor, Now I learned a little bit more about swing!

Well, then it would be better to revise my post for the sake of the questioner, right?

Comment: I'll give you a Vote up on the post as a small token of my gratitude.

Comment: @camickr I'm very sorry for bothering ㅠㅅㅠ 
Could you tell me if there is any part of the revised answer that needs to be more revisable, please? Thanks for your recommendation, I was able to study a little more deeply about the way I knew it was just one of the many ways!

Comment: The approach in the code is still wrong. For example change the setSize(…) statement to `setSize(500, 200)` and see what happens. The approach should be to first set the size of the component and then 2) determine the location of the component within the bounds of the parent container. This is how layout management works.